# Get both the current modified entity and the database entity snapshot with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, seam

We use seam as Java EE framework. I've controller which inherits from EntityHome. When user press 'Save' button, we have a modified entity instance, but not flushed this changes to database.

How can I retrieve this entity in two states(1st - database state, 2-nd user modified state)?

I've tried to use enityManager.refresh(object), but it's also reset all changes in user modified state of object.

I think about two sessions, but i wonder, if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. You clone the currently attached entity, using a deep-copy serialization/deserialization (that means all your entities should be serialable):

   ```
   MyEntity clonedObject = org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.clone(object);
   ```
2. Then you refresh the currently attached object:

   ```
   session.refresh(object);
   ```

Now you have both the modified object (e.g. `clonedObject`) and the original entity version (e.g. `object`).

If you want to merge the `clonedObject`, you can simply do it like this:

```
object = session.merge(clonedObject);
```